# Verifying ownership of a domain name purchased through Sqaurespace with AWS ACM

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, squarespace, aws-acm

I'm relatively new to the AWS ecosystem and have a question that I'm hoping I can properly articulate enough to get an answer.

I have an app that whose frontend is deployed through AWS Amplify and has a load balancer set up through EC2 for requests to the backend. When developing locally, all requests from the frontend to the backend have been made over HTTP and presented no problems. However, when deployed up into the AWS environment, the URL from the Amplify deploy is serving over HTTPS while the load balancer DNS uses HTTP, and so when the frontend makes a request to the server I get a Mixed Content error. I know that to get around this I need to essentially set up a domain for the load balancer and use ACM to generate an SSL certificate for it so that it can serve back responses over HTTPS.

However, to further complicate the situation, a domain has already been purchased by others on my team through Squarespace, which I'm required to use (my-app.co as an example here). I want to have "api.my-app.co" route to my load balancer so that I can make requests from the frontend to "api.my-app.co/items" to grab whatever I need from my database.

I haven't been able to find a definitive answer to my specific problem, but through various tutorials I've pieced together the following:

1. In my squarespace account, I've created a CNAME record for "api.my-app.co" and pointed it to my load balancer's DNS name
2. In ACM, I've generated a certificate for the "api.my-app.co" domain that is currently awaiting ownership validation.
3. I've also set up a Hosted Zone through Route 53 as described in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ookzXuMr8eY&ab_channel=EndreSynnes, though I'm unsure of how to supply the "Value/Route traffic to" values to Squarespace.
4. I know that once I get the certificate validated I need to provide it to an HTTPS listener on my load balancer, but I haven't yet been able to get to this point.

My main question is: How do I confirm ownership of the Squarespace domain using the DNS method? Unfortunately nothing I've read in ACM's documentation itself has been of much help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and I had meaningless error messages in squarespace (they didn't give any clue what was wrong), after many tests I managed to find the right combination.

NOTE: I think this was my biggest discovery, DO NOT click on the aws copy button, when you paste it into squarespace it will tell you that the domain is invalid and a couple of other things. Copy data manually (ctr+c)

requested domain name in aws: xxxyyy.com
Squarespace Host: put the aws CNAME Name without the domain at the end and without any period at the end.

Data Squarespace: put the aws CNAME Value without the period at the end

It should be validated within next 5 minutes

[image: result]

Comment: This worked for me - could not find it anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

> I've also set up a Hosted Zone through Route 53 as described in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ookzXuMr8eY&ab_channel=EndreSynnes, though I'm unsure of how to supply the "Value/Route traffic to" values to Squarespace.

You shouldn't have done that at all. You are using Squarespace as your DNS server. Setting up ***another*** DNS server on AWS isn't going to solve anything. Forget about Route53.

All you need to do is go into the ACM domain validation, and find the two DNS records it is asking you to create in order to verify you own the domain. Then go over to your Squarespace DNS settings, and add those two DNS records. After that, the ACM service should soon detect that you have created the records and then it will issue you the SSL certificate.

Comment: Just to confirm I'm understanding correctly, the redacted CNAME records found here on ACM:

https://imgur.com/FiHHWkw

need to be added alongside the CNAME record I already created on squarespace here?:

https://imgur.com/PtBRb0o

Comment: Yes, that is correct. It looks like there's just one CNAME you need to create. For some reason I was thinking there were 2 needed to validate. The `Name` value in ACM will be the `Host` value in Squarespace, and the `Value` value in ACM will be the `Data` value in Squarespace.

Comment: So strange - Squarespace is spitting a very nondescript error back at me when I try to add that record: Custom record not saved - We were unable to save this record. Try again later. If this problem continues, contact Customer Support. Not sure what's up.

Comment: If the host value that AWS Amplify provides is say `_3639ac514e785e898d2646601fa951d5.example.com.`, you need to enter only the first part `_3639ac514e785e898d2646601fa951d5` (i.e. omit the `.example.com.` part) into Squarespace. Ref https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002101888#toc-troubleshooting